# Deleting other symbols from first row in csv file?

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

I have multiple csv files that I export from an imaging software, but the first three rows are blank or have repeating "==" in the header (I've attached an image for reference).

I've figured out how to retrieve values from the last row using:

```
file_vec <- c(list.files('/path/to/files', 
                     full.names = TRUE, pattern = '\\.csv$'[-c(1)]))
dt_list <- lapply(file_vec, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
name_vec <- sub(".csv", "", file_vec)
dt_final <- data.frame(File = name_vec,
                   Value = sapply(dt_list, function(x) x[nrow(x), 2]),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

but this only works after I manually deleted the first three rows from my csv files in excel and then converted them back to csv. I've tried using the skip function and lapply, but when I use lapply it gives me an error in `read.table` because of the first three rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. For reference, my end goal is to pull out rows 28 and 51 in the 4th column from multiple csv files.

[image]

Comment: `dt_list <- lapply(file_vec, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, skip=3)`

Comment: wow that's a very quick fix, thank you! looks like I wasn't trying skip in the right location

Comment: Also stringsAsFactors = FALSE is the default unless you are using a very old version of R.

Comment: Well, very old... since April 2020.